# 'new pics' folder keeps appearing to desktop

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, itunes

A folder named 'new pics' keeps appearing on my desktop and I am not sure why. It has subdirs within it as follows:

**Folder Info**

- Name - 'new pics'
- Subdirs - 'Camera Roll/', 'Saved Pictures/'

I am using Win10 Home v1703 and think this may be generated from iPhone connection via iTunes or File Explorer. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your picture folder location may have been switched to the desktop. If you open file explorer, right click on the pictures folder and go to properties. There is a location tab, if you click on it, you can see if it's set to your desktop.

I tested it by moving it to a different folder and it automatically created the folder but none of the sub directories that you are getting. .

Comment: The subfolders were and are being created/recreated by the use of iPhone and iTunes, as hypothesized by the OP.